# PHP + mySQL - Getting a shared position of row after count query

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to display individual ranks of each seller within their panel on my marketplace site. For this specific rank, I'm counting how many followers each seller has, ordering the list in descending order, and then getting the position of each one so they know where they rank. I'm using a query that works, except when two sellers have the same number of followers, the position changes every time. This is especially bothersome when there are large number of sellers with the same number of followers.

Query (in PHP):

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT rank
        FROM (
          SELECT vendor_id, followers, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
          FROM (
            SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(*) AS followers
            FROM $table
            GROUP BY vendor_id
            ORDER BY followers DESC
           ) as sq,
            (SELECT @rank:=0) AS tr
          ) as q WHERE vendor_id = $vendorId";
?>
```

where `$vendorId` = the current seller's ID.

So, again, the main issue is that if there are 10 sellers, and 7 of them all have 1 follower. Each time the seller refreshes, they'll see a ranking anywhere from 4-10. I'd like it to just say 4 for all sellers who have the 1 follower.

Update: The following query has given me what I wanted, though I'd still prefer pushing the workload to PHP than keeping it all on MySQL.

```
<?php
    $connection->query("SET @curRank:=1, @prevRank:=0, @incRank=1;");

    $query = "SELECT rank
    FROM (
    SELECT vendor_id, followers,
      @curRank := IF(@prevRank = followers, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank,
      @incRank := @incRank + 1,
      @prevRank := followers
        FROM (
    SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(1) AS followers
    FROM $favTable
            GROUP BY vendor_id
    ORDER BY followers DESC, vendor_id DESC
        ) as sq,
        (SELECT @rank:=0) AS tr
     ) as q WHERE vendor_id = $vendorId";

    $result = $connection->fetchOne($query);
```

Comment: Store followers in a variable `@oldfollowers`, only increment `@rank` if new followers < `@oldfollowers`. However, what rank would number 11 with 0 followers be? 5 or 11? Or, if you're using PHP: why are you needlessly complicating things by forcing this on MySQL while it's a breeze to just handle this in PHP easily?

Comment: Aside: [MYSQL 8 supports rank()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) (which is what you're looking for), some pre-that-version workaround can be [seen here](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2016/04/analytical-function-in-mysql-rownumber.html)

Comment: Of course, you could just do the ranking in PHP

Comment: ^ Listen to that man :). Make life easy on yourself and the next dev touching your codebase, 'clever' code of the 'oneliner/one call' variant  is nightmarish to maintain :)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on the best way with PHP? I've tried searching but all the results end up with people answering with MySQL queries such as mine. I would definitely prefer to do it in PHP.

Would it be possible to return the query as an array, and then find the position of the exact vendor in that array? Like using `array_search`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  on the right path. You just need to add a couple more vars in the query.
You could try the following:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT rank
    FROM (
      SELECT vendor_id, followers,
          @curRank := IF(@prevRank = followers, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank, 
          @incRank := @incRank + 1, 
          @prevRank := followers
      FROM (
        SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(*) AS followers
        FROM $table
        GROUP BY vendor_id
        ORDER BY followers DESC, vendor_id
       ) as sq,
        (SELECT @rank:=0) AS tr
      ) as q WHERE vendor_id = $vendorId";
?>
```

Please add a more specific sort order as mentioned by @swa66 to get consistent ordered rows. When the field used in sort has same values, mysql may return rows based on its own ordering logic.

Comment: The issue here is that I don't want it to sort by `vendor_id`, as the ranking would also depend on their id; ranking users with a lower or higher id wouldn't be an honest ranking.

Comment: It does not rank them by id. If you execute this SQL, you would see that the ordering is on number of followers. When the number of followers is same for more than 1 vendor then they are all allotted the same rank. The vendor id helps to keep the list of same ranked vendors consistent during multiple calls.

Comment: Here is a sample SQL fiddle. I assume you need sum of followers and not count of followers based on the name of the field. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6312bb/4

Comment: Each row in the table contains information about an exact "follow". So the `vendor_id`, `createed_at`, customer info. In order to find how many followers a seller actually has, I need to count each row by the seller's ID (`vendor_id`). Your solution works in theory, and in the sqlfiddle, however when trying to apply it, it returns NULL as the rank.

Comment: I've found that I cannot run two queries in a single go. I have to set `@curRank`, `@prevRank` and `@incRank` in a separate query I suppose.